# Why is my Sony Vaio laptop randomly turning off?

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, sony-vaio, diagnostic

These are the things I am seeing now.
Sometimes, my computer turns on and can run for as long as a few days without ever the need for a restart or anything for that matter.
Sometimes, when it is off and I want to turn it on, after a few seconds (usually before the Windows starts loading), it suddenly goes off. No warning. Just all lights out.
Sometimes, it does this after a few minutes,
sometimes, it doesn't do it at all.

What can cause this?

PS. No batteries are attached. I am running Windows 10 Pro (activated), and temperatures are normal (at least my hardware diagnosis apps are telling me so).

Thank you very much!

Comment: See if the input jack for the AC Adapter is loose.  You may need to open the laptop to know. I have had this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has no battery, then the charging circuitry - whose job it is to charge the battery from which the computer draws its power - is being subjected to unusual stress. Startup is going to be a larger power draw than any other time.

Its job is not to run the computer, it is not powerful enough to do that. Its job is to charge the battery, which has been removed.

The solution would be to replace the battery.